# How to run multiple faunadb queries sequentially in the one request?

Tags: faunadb

I want to create a collection, then create an index on that collection. An array of queries is valid FQL, so I tried this:

```
[
  CreateCollection({ name: "users" }),
  CreateIndex({
    name: "users_by_email",
    permissions: { read: "public" },
    source: Collection("users"),
    terms: [{field: ["data", "email"]}],
    unique: true
  })
]
```

But it fails with a `Cannot read reference` error. I think this is because it tries to get the `Collection("users")` for the second part before creating it.

Is it possible to execute multiple queries *sequentially* in the one call to faunadb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for. The `Do` function can run a list of statements sequentially

https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/do?lang=javascript

Comment: Thanks! This answers the general question of sequentiality, though sadly I've realized it doesn't work for the specific case of creating a collection and then an index, because that can't be done in the same transaction. "The index [...] may not be created in the same transaction as its source collection(s)." https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/createindex?lang=javascript